# How could i add my web App name in url use Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

How could i add my web App name in url use Node.js?

My Web run with http://127.0.0.1:8080

I want to add pathname /myapp like

http://127.0.0.1:8080/myapp

Comment: This sounds like you need to learn about routes.

Comment: You can just define path parameter to look like this. Learn about routing. can also configure your server to redirect any requests from specific pathname to your app.

Comment: yes, in server.js i setting  app.use('appName', routes) but i got error say can't find my login page

Comment: maybe update your question with mentioned code plus error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using express follow this documentation

https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

In vanilla Node js you can do this

```
const http = require('http');
const url = require('url');

// Routes
const router = {
    /* '/myapp' route will be handled here and following function will be executed */
    'myapp': function (callback) {
        //we expect a callback function as argument
        callback(200, { name: 'sample handler' });
        //execute the callback function and pass 200 status code and a sample data which will send as response payload to user
    },
    'login': function(callback){
        callback(200, { name: 'Login' }); //You can add your routes in this object and handle them
    }
};

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    // Get URL
    const parsedURL = url.parse(req.url, true);

    // Get Path
    const path = parsedURL.pathname; //This will give **http://127.0.0.1:8080/myapp **
    const trimmedPath = path.replace(/^\/+|\/+$/g, '');
    //This will get routes specified after base url in our case **myapp**

    req.on('data', (data) => {
        // streamed data. Browser will send data in stream, this func will run on each stream
    });

    // When Request in ended, all user requests can be handled in this event
    req.on('end', () => {
        // Handle Routes
        const choosenHandler = router[trimmedPath]; //Check in route obj

        //Send the callback function which was required
        choosenHandler(function (statusCode, payload) {
            // Send response to user
            const payloadString = JSON.stringify(payload);

            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
            res.writeHead(statusCode);
            res.write('<h1>Data: ' + payloadString + '</h1>'); //This will be sent to user
            console.log('returning response');
            res.end();
        });
    });
});

// Start the server
server.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Server Listening to 3000 port ');
});
```

Comment: I setting routes.get('/', errorHandle(viewLogin)) to redirect my login page,and setting routes.post('/login', errorHandle(login)); to my login controller

Comment: Thanks, I found my mistake because I did not update my routing, thank you for your answer